# How to show changed file list by a specific author in a Git repository?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-log

How to show changed files by a specific author in a Git repository?

When I use this command `git log --numstat --pretty=tformat:'%an'`,

git bash will group files by the author, like this:

```
WoJiaoChaDi-YSS
16      6       AHKScriptManager/scripts/AutoInput/HotKeyString.ini
1       1       AHKScriptManager/scripts/RemindMe/RemindConfig.ini
21      0       OneQuick.Ext.ahk

WoJiaoChaDi-PC
1       1       AHKScriptManager/scripts/AutoCapture/config.ini
```

but I want to get result like this: (author in every line head posistion)

```
WoJiaoChaDi-YSS      16      6       AHKScriptManager/scripts/AutoInput/HotKeyString.ini
WoJiaoChaDi-YSS      1       1       AHKScriptManager/scripts/RemindMe/RemindConfig.ini
WoJiaoChaDi-YSS      21      0       OneQuick.Ext.ahk

WoJiaoChaDi-PC       1       1       AHKScriptManager/scripts/AutoCapture/config.ini
```

so, who can help me？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with some bash scripting:

```
#!/bin/bash

git log --pretty=tformat:'%H;%an' | while IFS=';' read COMMIT AUTHOR; do
  git log --max-count=1 --numstat --pretty=tformat:'' "$COMMIT" | sed "s/^\(.\)/$AUTHOR\t\1/"
  printf "\n"
done
```

Comment: Thaks borther, It worked very perfect in my git bash!!

Comment: @WoJiaoChaDi, be sure to upvote helpful answers then, please.

Comment: @GabrielStaples  yeah, That is I should do, I have clicked the button

Comment: Looks like someone deleted my comment mentioning @WoJiaoChaDi hadn't upvoted this answer they marked as correct--which they haven't--because I'm the only one who has upvoted this answer right now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for providing way for this question, user14967413 brother.

And I have an other way to do that, like this:

```
git log --numstat --pretty=format:'%an' | awk '{x=$0;tmp=$1""$2;
    if(tmp!~/^[0-9]+$/ && tmp!~/\-\-/){
        name=$0
    } else {
        OFS="\t"
        print name, $0
    }
}'
```

It is harvest that I have learned awk syntax for 2 hours.

Comment: Author names could contain a space, so you should rather use `name=$0`, otherwise it will print only the first name. :-)

Comment: yes, you are right, I didn't take this point. xD